# Linux+Java+Odbc+Progres

Tags: java, linux, odbc, openedge, progress-db

Hi I need to connect a Java Application on a Linux server to Progress database. I use to connect an odbc configured on Linux server, it work correctly, from command line can I make querys. The problem is when I try to get the connection connect from Java Application I'm getting a null pointer.

Java version 1.6.0_45
OS: CentOS release 6.5
ODBC Progress: working OK

This is the body of a method to test de Insert into Progress

```
try {
        String bd = "dbToWrite";
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:" + bd;
        String user = "root";
        String psw = "root";
        Connection con;
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, psw);
        PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PUB.\"mo-chsu\" "
                + "(\"c-expt\", \"c-tisu\", \"i-cheq\","
                + " \"c-a#o\", nombre, apellido, "
                + "\"n-tarj\", \"c-cat\", varios, "
                + "\"s-sac\", embar, otros, "
                + "jubi, \"ti-doc\", \"num-doc\", "
                + "\"co-min\", \"n-liq\", fonavi,"
                + " club,\"n-mes\", anioe)"
                + "VALUES (9999,999,9999.99,"
                + "2014,'XXXX','XXXX',"
                + "999,5,888.88,"
                + "1.0,2.0,3.0,"
                + "4.44,9,99999999,"
                + "1,9,3000,"
                + "30.0,9,2014)");
        ps1.execute();

        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Exception is, doesn't say too much:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.initialize(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:436)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:153)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at Main.conexionProgress(Main.java:23)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

I think the problem is a library on Java... but I can find witch one.

Please give me a hand! Thanks
Sorry my english :)

Comment: Here you have an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/ConnecttoAccessDatabaseusingJDBCODBCbridge.htm) that you can try. By the way, you also can try changing you driver jar to another version

Comment: I think the ODBC bridge is only available on Windows systems.

Comment: Thanks for the help. About the driver, I try with 3 versions, but in progress documentation indicate to use the one that is provided by them. About the odbc bridge, works perfect from linux commnad line, the problem is in something with java, in windows with the same test and odbc bridge configured, works perfect, that is why I say the problem it's between linux, odbc and java.